# tf-idf sickitlearn separate "word" from word

Tags: python, text-classification, tf-idf

I am working with a problem in text classification where If a word was found in this format **"word"** it will have a different importance from if found in this format **word**  so I tried this code

```
    import re
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    sent1 = "The cat sat on my \"face\" face"
    sent2 = "The dog sat on my bed"
    content = [sent1,sent2]
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'")
    vectorizer.fit(content)
    print (vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

The result was

```
    ['"', 'bed', 'cat', 'dog', 'face', 'my', 'on', 'sat', 'the']
```

Where I wished it would be

```
    ['bed', 'cat', 'dog', 'face','"face"' 'my', 'on', 'sat', 'the']
```

Comment: this is a tokenisation problem. Either fix the `token_pattern` to capture the case of double quotes, or supply a `tokeniser` callable to `CountVectorizer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your token pattern is

```
token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'"
```

which is looking for words (\b\w\w+\b) or exclamation marks, or question marks, or quotation marks. Try something like

```
token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|\"\b\w\w+\b\"|!|\?|\'"
```

Note the part

```
\"\b\w\w+\b\"
```

which looks for a word surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `token_pattern` parameter to your needs. The following should work for the provided example:

```
pattern = r"\S+[^!?.\s]"
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=pattern)
```

You may, however, need to further refine the pattern. https://regex101.com may be helpful to get your regex just right.